# Updating Tkinter text with label

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a GUI version of a drinking game, which involves throwing dice. I 'throw the dice' virtually, but want to display the outcome on the screen. I thought using `Label()` would be most useful, but i'm having trouble updating that text (the `throw_text` variable) when a new dice throw is done.
Instead of the text updating on the screen, a new text appears below the previous one with the new throw.
I don't want a cascading stream of text, but just one singular text that updates at the dice being thrown i.e. when the 'Roll!' button is pressed.

I've seen people do it using the `Stringvar()`, however i must be doing it wrong as it does not have an effect on the appearance.

```
from tkinter import *

dim = [900, 600]

root = Tk()
root.geometry(f"{dim[0]}x{dim[1]}")
root.title("Mex")
root.iconbitmap("dice.ico")

lbl = Label(root, font=("Times", 200))

num = ['\u2680', '\u2681', '\u2682', '\u2683', '\u2684', '\u2685']
d1 = None
d2 = None

throw_txt = StringVar()


def roll_dice():
    global d1, d2
    d1 = random.choice(num)
    d2 = random.choice(num)
    lbl.config(text=f"{d1}{d2}")
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.place(x=dim[0] / 3.8, y=50)

    print("Throw:", check_throw(convert_symbol()))

    throw_txt = str(check_throw(convert_symbol()))
    txt = Label(root, text=throw_txt)
    txt.pack(side=TOP)


def convert_symbol():
    d1_num = None
    d2_num = None
    for n in num:
        if n == d1:
            d1_num = num.index(n) + 1
        if n == d2:
            d2_num = num.index(n) + 1
    if d2_num > d1_num:
        throw = f"{d2_num}{d1_num}"
    else:
        throw = f"{d1_num}{d2_num}"
    return throw


def check_throw(t):
    num_t = int(t)
    if num_t == 21:
        return "Mex"
    elif num_t % 11 == 0:
        return f"Koning: {int(num_t / 11 * 100)}"
    elif num_t % 31 == 0:
        return "Slok uitdelen"
    else:
        return str(num_t)


roll_btn = Button(root, text="Roll!", width=10, command=roll_dice)
roll_btn.config(font=("Bahnschrift", 20))
roll_btn.pack()
roll_btn.place(x=dim[0] / 2.5, y=25)

roll_btn = Button(root, text="Convert", width=10, command=convert_symbol)
roll_btn.config(font=("Bahnschrift", 20))
roll_btn.pack()
roll_btn.place(x=dim[0] / 2.5, y=500)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: btw, the way to use `StringVar` is to use its `.set()` method, where basically You set the StringVar instance as textvariable for the Label and then You call the `instance.set('new text')` where `instance` is the StringVar instance e.g.: `instance = StringVar()` (`textvariable=instance`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
when a new dice throw is done. Instead of the text updating on the screen, a new text appears below the previous one with the new throw. I don't want a cascading stream of text,  but just one singular text that updates at the dice being thrown i.e. when the 'Roll!' button is pressed.
```

Used `txt.configure` to see updates when new dice throw. You can see updates on label.

Change this:

```
def roll_dice():
    global d1, d2
    d1 = random.choice(num)
    d2 = random.choice(num)
    lbl.config(text=f"{d1}{d2}")
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.place(x=dim[0] / 3.8, y=50)

    print("Throw:", check_throw(convert_symbol()))

    throw_txt = str(check_throw(convert_symbol()))
    txt = Label(root, text=throw_txt)
    txt.pack(side=TOP)
```

to:

```
def roll_dice():
    global d1, d2
    d1 = random.choice(num)
    d2 = random.choice(num)
    lbl.config(text=f"{d1}{d2}")
    lbl.pack()
    lbl.place(x=dim[0] / 3.8, y=50)

    print("Throw:", check_throw(convert_symbol()))

    throw_txt = str(check_throw(convert_symbol()))
    txt.configure(text=throw_txt)
```

...

Put the `Label` widget outside of `roll_dice()` function.

```
txt = Label(root)
txt.pack(side=TOP)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `configure` attribute instead of storing the text of the Label widget into a separate variable.

**Take a quick look at this code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("my game")

def change_text():
    mylabel.configure(text="You just hit the button!")

mylabel = Label(root, text="Hit the button pls")
mylabel.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w')

mybutton = Button(root, text="Click me", command=change_text)
mybutton.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='w')

root.mainloop()
```